# What is the correct way to transfer/pass an xml document/string to php from javascript or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I am obtaining an xml from a remote server using jquery.

I am then creating an xml document using

```
$.parseXML()
```

in jQuery, (which is new to version 1.5 of jQuery)

That side of things works well, however i am not sure what the best way is to then pass this xml document to a php file so that the contents can be saved to a mysql database.

It doesnt seem possible to pass the xml to php as a variable via the get method.

Does the xml document need to be serialized?
Should i be using $.parseXML() prior to sending it to the php script or not?

There must be a correct way to do this?

Any discussion on this is very welcome?

Comment: Does it have to be XML? Is json not an option?

Comment: Use ajax (or regular form submission) to pass the raw .xml string to PHP, which can then use its own DOM handlers to parse the stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try. If i use get firebug returns '414 URI too large'